# Encrypting USB and making it only accessible on specific computers

Tags: usb, encryption

I have a small office of only 8 computers (4 iMacs and 4 PCs).

I would like to block all external USBs and only allow encrypted ones that can only be accessible on these 8 computers because they contain sensitive data.

I have some knowledge in IT but I haven't done anything like that before.

Comment: The hard part will be to block all unencrypted ones.

Comment: Did you consider encrypting it and giving the key to the 8 computers owners.

Comment: You can use something like this : https://github.com/inversepath/interlock